# ListView items won't show focus color when click

Tags: android

When i click on listview, its not show the focus color .

> ```
> <ListView
>          android:id="@+id/android:list"
>          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>          android:divider="@color/grey"
>          android:dividerHeight="1px" 
>          android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
>          android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`ListView`s do not show focus (or selection) while in touch mode. You will only see this when you use the hardware keyboard or controls to navigate your UI.

See the Google [Touch Mode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html) Android Blog article for more details.

So, if you are only using touch mode, you will never see focus or selection on `ListView`s.

Answer (score 1):

if you use transparent color then how it will be see..
just change your color...

Comment: if i set another color then also i m not able to see focus color .

Comment: remove this property..android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: just remove this all property and check it          android:divider="@color/grey"
         android:dividerHeight="1px" 
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
         android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"